# mlflow.exceptions.RestException: RESOURCE_DOES_NOT_EXIST: No Experiment with id=0 exists

Tags: python-3.6

Hi I met strange issue as following:

```
File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mlflow/tracking/fluent.py", line 138, in start_run
    tags=tags
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mlflow/tracking/client.py", line 88, in create_run
    tags=[RunTag(key, value) for (key, value) in iteritems(tags)]
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mlflow/store/rest_store.py", line 158, in create_run
    response_proto = self._call_endpoint(CreateRun, req_body)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mlflow/store/rest_store.py", line 69, in _call_endpoint
    response = self._verify_rest_response(response, endpoint)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mlflow/store/rest_store.py", line 52, in _verify_rest_response
    return verify_rest_response(response, endpoint)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mlflow/utils/rest_utils.py", line 84, in verify_rest_response
    raise RestException(json.loads(response.text))
mlflow.exceptions.RestException: RESOURCE_DOES_NOT_EXIST: No Experiment with id=0 exists
```